# Orchestration of tasks ran in parallel blocks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

)

I'm facing a problem and hope you'll be able to give me hand :-)

**The problem**

I'm trying to write a pipeline like the one below:

```
parallel(
    "task A": { build some stuff and run verifications},
    "task B": { build more stuff. Wait for task A to be finished. Run tests.},
    "task C": { build some more stuff. Wait for task A to be finished. Run tests.}
)
```

My problem is I can't find a way to wait for the completion of task A.

**Things I've tried**

*Store the result of the build*

In "task A", I would run the job like this: `job_a = build job: "Job_A"`
Then in task B and C, I would use the attributes of "job_a".
Unfortunately this doesn't work as I get an error because job_a is not defined (in the scope of task B ans C). There might a forks happening when using "parallel".
I also tried defining "job_a" before the parallel block and still assign the job to it in "task A" but this did not work either as in task B and task C, job_a would only have the value that was first defined.

*Schedule task A outside the parallel block*

I also tried scheduling the job directly before the parallel block.
I would get a job object and then directly run job.scheduleBuild2.
Here again no success.

**Any idea how to do this?**

The main reasons I would like to set up the pipeline this way is:

1. All these jobs run on slaves (most likely different).
2. If task A is finished, and the build of task B is finished, the tests should start. Even if the build of task C hasn't finished yet.
3. Same if task C finishes before task B.

I'd be very grateful if you have an idea how to implement this :-)
More generally I'm also curious of how this all work behind the scenes.
Indeed, when running parallel several processes or threads must be used. How does the master keeps communicating with a slave during a build to update status etc.

Thanks a lot :-D

Comment: I am not exactly sure what these attributes are that you want to pass to job B and C (In the Store result of the build section). Are those results files or actual objects in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Hey! So "build job" returns an object that has a "result" property. From what I've seen, result is either set to null (job still running), failure, success or unstable. My idea was to poll the result and wait while result is null. Is it clearer?

Comment: Another clarification: all I am looking for, is a way to wait for the completion of "task A" from inside the task B/C parallel block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a solution to your problem but I was only able to come up with something close to what your are asking for. As far as I am aware, parallel in Jenkinsfiles is currently implemented in a way which does not support communication between the different processes running in parallel. Each one of your parallel tasks is run in its own sandbox and therefor cannot access information about the other directly.

One solution could be the following:

- A,B and C are started in parallel
- B or C finishes its first stage and now need A to continue
- Introduce a waiting stage into B and C
- B and/or C poll the Jenkins remote api of A (`http://jenkins/job/job.A/lastBuild/api/json`) and look for the result entry
- If result is null -> keep waiting, if result is `SUCCESS` -> continue, if result is `FAILURE` throw exception and so on

The obvious downside for this solution is, that you have to implement that stage and do actual HTTP calls to get the JSON responses.

Another Solution could be:

- Split B and C into two jobs each
- Run the first parts of B and C in parallel with A
- Run the second part of B and C in parallel once the first parallel stage has finished

The downside here would be, that it is slower than the setup your wish for in your question. But it would be considerably less effort to implement.

Comment: Thanks Bricktop for your answer. I appreciate you putting time to look into this :-) I understand the need of sandboxing parallel jobs. I thought I'd be able to query the status _via_ the master. As you described, both solutions have pro and cons. I do prefer the first one (will implement it), cause in the second if the build of C cannot be scheduled soon, the tests won't start for a long time. I'm just surprised there doesn't seem to be a "join" mechanism or is there one, just not compatible with parallel?

Comment: I did look for an operation like that before but I was unable to find it. AFAIK Jenkins pipelines are still heavily under development and still in adoption, so I hope that something like that comes along in the future.